# Force new _id generation in embedded MongoDB documents

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 3, C# and MongoDB. I have a model with embedded documents, but I would like to auto-generate a new _id for each of my embedded documents.

I can do this in the code and set

```
Model._id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
```

But I would love it if I didn't have to worry about doing this and let MongoDB auto-generate the new _id for each embedded document.

I do not want to normalize out these embedded documents into a new collection, they make sense here, but I'd like to have a unique ID for them.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you need to have an id on embedded documents? I think that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I wanted to have Id's because I still need to uniquely identify the documents even though they are embedded. These objects are editable individually, but only belong to one parent document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only `ObjectId` that MongoDB "auto-generates" is the one it uses for the primary key: `_id`.

When you save a document, MongoDB knows basically nothing about "schema" or "embedded" documents or "arrays of sub-documents". There's no type-checking or schema validation, so there's no way to force the instantiation of the embedded IDs.

Your best bet is to wrap it up in the parent class. If those embedded documents have a specific class tied to them, you can put the `GenerateNewId()` in that constructor.